# Linking listbox with access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox

Hey guys kinda new here. 
I just want to ask how to link a Access database to a listbox? My database consists of Customer id, Customer address, Customer contact. I want the listbox to be link with database so when i start the application, the Customer names in the database will display in the listbox. I also want to be able to click the names in the listbox and will display the rest of the customer info in textboxes like the address and the contact number. I'm developing this application in C# using visual studio 2010. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not very convenient to use a `ListBox` that way. `ListBox` is just for simple data representation. You should go for `DataGridView`, or at least `ListView`.

Comment: You must specify proper tags, c# is general when it comes to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS 2010 to do this:

1. drag a Listbox from toolbox to the page;
2. Click choose Data Source to link to Access Database,binding
   DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID";
3. Add event SelectedIndexChanged to this listbox, then add code to
   pull data from access database where customer id equals the id you
   select, then display the value to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If your new to C# then I think you need read up on **ADO.NET** as giving you simple code snippets will not help you in the long run.

**ADO.NET** will allow you to connect up to your database and perform **READ , INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE** functions.

In your case you simply need to be able to read data in from the Access database file.

You will need to learn about using `OledbAdapaters`, `OledbDataReaders`, `DataTables`, `OledbConnections` and so on.

There are many example of using this technology all over the internet. Infact if you look through the questions that I've asked / answered on here you will find code snippets all about ADO.NET.